# ciclo for no se detiene

Tags: c++

Este código esta mal y no se porque, quiero hacer un `array[5]={1,2,3,4,5,6}` y mostrarlo en pantalla.

```
int main(void){

    int arr[5];
    arr[0]=1;
    arr[1]=2;
    arr[2]=3;
    arr[3]=4;
    arr[4]=5;
    arr[5]=6;

    for(int i=0; i<=5; i++) cout<<arr[i]<<endl;

return 0;}
```

El programa se ejecuta, pero muestra esto:

```
position: 0 data: 1
position: 1 data: 2
position: 2 data: 3
position: 3 data: 4
position: 4 data: 5
position: 5 data: 0
position: 6 data: 4196822
position: 7 data: 0
position: 8 data: 0
position: 9 data: 0
position: 10 data: 0
position: 11 data: 0
position: 12 data: 4196822
position: 13 data: 0
position: 14 data: -982238395
position: 15 data: 27786
...
```

Comment: No se nada sobre c++, una cosa, que por cierto no soluciona tu problema, pero tu array deberia estar declarado en 6. Por cierto no encuentro problemas en tu for ya que esta bien, no se cual sea tu problema.

Comment: El código que presentas no coincide con la salida que muestras. En la salida se ve escrito `position: X data: Y` mientras que tu código dice que sólo debería mostrar `X`. Por favor: comparte el código exácto que te da el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema de su código se debe a las siguientes líneas:

```
int arr[5];
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=2;
arr[2]=3;
arr[3]=4;
arr[4]=5;
arr[5]=6;
```

El anterior código hace lo siguiente:

1) Crear un arreglo de 5 enteros, esto significa que el programa le solicita al Sistema Operativo que le dé un espacio de memoria (contiguo) para almacenar 5 enteros, en 5 'casillas' diferentes.
2) Con este espacio de memoria el programa le asigna a la primera casilla el número 1, a la segunda casilla el número 2, ..., a la quinta casilla el número 5 y ¡a la sexta casilla el número 6!.

El problema aquí es que usted le solicitó al Sistema Operativo espacio para almacenar 5 variables de tipo entero de forma contigua pero usted está accediendo a un espacio más allá del reservado (un sexto valor). Mientras esta región se encuentre en los límites de todo el espacio de memoria que se reserva a su programa, el código seguirá 'funcionando', el inconveniente es que más allá del espacio que el SO reservó (conocido como stack) se encuentran otras variables importantes de su programa, entre ellas aquellas que controlan el flujo correcto del ciclo for (muy probablemente el valor que toma la variable i para que la condición i<=5 sea siempre verdadera).

La solución a este problema es siempre verificar que no se manipule un arreglo declarado más allá de los límites en los que lo creó. Si necesita almacenar 6 variables enteras, debería declarar el arreglo como

```
int arr[6];
```

y manipular nuevamente cada 'casilla' desde arr[0] hasta arr[n-1] donde n es el tamaño original del arreglo. Hacer operaciones más allá de estos arreglos es permitido (porque el lenguaje no ofrece chequeo de límites) y produce comportamiento indefinido.

**Información adicional**

**NO** siempre ocurre un ciclo infinito. Esto depende del Sistema Operativo en el que se compile y ejecute, del compilador usado y de la arquitectura del equipo donde se ejecute el programa, pero en general es impredecible saber qué puede suceder.

Comment: *entre ellas aquellas que controlan el flujo correcto del ciclo for (muy probablemente el valor que toma la variable i para que la condición i<=5 sea siempre verdadera).* Si la variable `i` se ha corrompido, no se mostaría el contenido de `arr` correctamente al inicio ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

Sin ejecutar tu código, solo a ojo, el array está mal declarado. Si haces int arr[5], el máximo índice es arr[4] (comienza a contar por 0). Si quieres un array para 6 elementos, deberías hacer int arr[6].

Sería cosa de mirarlo con un depurador, pero puede que ese índice al que estas accediendo fuera de rango, arr[5], esté en realidad sobreescribiendo algún dato interno de la función. Puesto que el array es local a la función, se crea en la pila. Ese arr[5] está accediendo a algún elemento de la pila que el compilador utiliza (alguna variable temporal interna, la dirección de retorno, o cualquier otra cosa).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la siguiente correccion:

```
int main(void){

int arr[6];
arr[0]=1;
arr[1]=2;
arr[2]=3;
arr[3]=4;
arr[4]=5;
arr[5]=6;

for(int i=0; i < 6; i++)    {cout<<arr[i]<<endl;} return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error está que originalmente declaraste un array de tamaño 5, pero le asignaste 6 valores, los punteros se vuelven locos al punto que se metieron con la memoria, en C++ es típico que esto suceda. Parece que existe una confusión del indice con el valor. Un tip con las condiciones del for, usa el mismo tamaño del array sin el signo igual, por ejemplo, si tienes `int array[20]`, que la condición del for sea `i < 20`

Answer (score 0):

Como todos indican, tu inconveniente es que declaraste un array para 5 elementos y colocaste 6. Adicionalmente a esto, C++ coloca en el lugar N+1 un carácter de fin de cadena "\0" y tú lo estas sobreescribiendo con el valor 6. Esto hace que el ciclo no se detenga nunca porque no encuentra el fin de cadena. De todas formas, el código que muestras no se condice con la salida que pusiste. Si tu código es el correcto, solo deberia mostrar los primeros 5 elementos porque tu "for" es de 1 a 5.